# Initialize deep map nesting in go structs

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

To initialize a map in a struct one should do the following:

```
someStruct.nestedMap = make(map[int8]int8)
```

But what should you do if you have a code structure like this:

```
type Base struct {
    base map[int8]uint64
}

type Middle struct {
    baseObjects map[int8]Base
}

type Top struct {
    middleObjects map[int8]Middle
}
```

There we have a total of 3 structs where each has a struct as a key.
How do you initialize this, and make it ready to go?

Comment: Write `NewTop` and `NewMiddle` and `NewBase` respectively. What have you tried and what problem did you meet?

Comment: Could you please write a simple example? I don't quite follow.

Comment: What problem do you have? When trying what?

Comment: I have a problem with not understanding of how to properly code that, frankly speaking.


I understand that I perhaps should create concrete objects of respective structs, but how to properly write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is auctually a map with default value that is not zero value, but a value ready to use, in this case, a made map.

Before going to the solution, there auctually is an issue about go here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3117

For reasons, Go now does not support to assign to a field of a struct if the struct is stored in a map.

To solve the issue, you need to use a pointer to that struct, and store the pointer in the map instead. So your data structure needs to be changed like:

```
type Base struct {
    base map[int8]uint64
}

type Middle struct {
    baseObjects map[int8]*Base
}

type Top struct {
    middleObjects map[int8]*Middle
}
```

And to the core logic: a defualt value map. Go does not support that with plain maps, but we can extend it, using methods to wrap it around.

```
func (t Top) Get(i int8) *Middle {
    x, ok := t.middleObjects[i]
    if !ok {
        v := NewMiddle()
        t.middleObjects[i] = v
        return v
    }

    return x
}

func (m Middle) Get(i int8) *Base {
    x, ok := m.baseObjects[i]
    if !ok {
        v := NewBase()
        m.baseObjects[i] = v
        return v
    }

    return x
}
```

When we are trying to get a value, we first check if it exists. If not, we return a new constructed one, and if it did exist, return the value.

Usage:

```
t.Get(8).Get(9).base[10] = 14
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/0JSN0yjRPif

Comment: I really grateful to you for that example. Will take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize the topmost struct `Top` with an empty map as value for its `middleObjects` property, calling any index on an empty map returns a zero value for the type the map holds.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Base struct {
    base map[int8]uint64
}

type Middle struct {
    baseObjects map[int8]Base
}

type Top struct {
    middleObjects map[int8]Middle
}

func main() {
    top := Top{
        middleObjects: make(map[int8]Middle),
    }

    // Outputs: "Top: {map[]}"
    fmt.Printf("Top: %v\n", top)

    // Outputs: "Base element: 0"
    fmt.Printf("Base element: %v\n", top.middleObjects[5].baseObjects[3].base[0])
}
```

Run the example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ldIpWtTjQ1M)

---

Edit:

You could also initialize the `Top` struct with a couple of elements, in any case it depends on how many elements you require each map to have at initialization:

```
func main() {
    top := Top{
        middleObjects: map[int8]Middle{
            0: Middle{
                baseObjects: map[int8]Base{
                    0: Base{
                        base: map[int8]uint64{
                            0: 1234,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    // After that you have to add one by one
    top.middleObjects[5] = Middle{
        baseObjects: map[int8]Base{
            0: Base{
                base: map[int8]uint64{
                    0: 123456,
                },
            },
        },
    }
    // If there's a middleObject with that index
    top.middleObjects[0].baseObjects[1] = Base{
        base: map[int8]uint64{
            0: 1111,
        },
    }

    // Outputs: "Base element: 1234"
    fmt.Printf("Base element: %v\n", top.middleObjects[0].baseObjects[0].base[0])
    // Outputs: "Base element: 123456"
    fmt.Printf("Base element: %v\n", top.middleObjects[5].baseObjects[0].base[0])
    // Outputs: "Base element: 1111"
    fmt.Printf("Base element: %v\n", top.middleObjects[0].baseObjects[1].base[0])

    top.middleObjects[0].baseObjects[0].base[0] = 2222
    // Outputs: "Base element: 2222"
    fmt.Printf("Base element: %v\n", top.middleObjects[0].baseObjects[0].base[0])
}
```

Run example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/zrZa-8JCSfH)

Comment: Yes, but if I try to assign and integer like that: `top.middleObjects[5].baseObjects[3].base[0] = 10`

it will panic with **panic: assignment to entry in nil map**.

And if I try to make a map like that: `top.middleObjects[5].baseObjects[3].base = make(map[int8]uint64)`

It willl panic this way: **cannot assign to struct field top.middleObjects[5].baseObjects[3].base in map**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll take a look at the example you've provided.